# GKE metadata service port conflict with NFS client

Tags: nfs, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running Google Kubernetes Engine (version 1.18.17-gke.1200) with Workload Identity enabled. There are 6 nodes in the cluster. On *two* of the nodes the `gke-metadata-server` Pod is failing with this error:

> Metadata Server stopped unexpectedly: failed to prepare Metadata
> Server: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:988: bind: address already in use

Running `netstat -tn` on the problematic node we see this:

```
tcp    0    0 10.0.11.218:988    172.16.1.10:2049    ESTABLISHED -
```

10.0.11.218 is the IP address of the node while 172.16.1.10 is the address of a Google Filestore instance.

My guess is that some other Pod on this node is connecting to Google Filestore (i.e., NFS) and using a low-numbered port which, unluckily, turned out to be 988 (the GKE Metadata Service running on each node uses port 988).

Is there some way to tell GKE or the Pod to not use port 988 when connecting to NFS?

Comment: Could you instead hard code the port for NFS or use the ephemeral ports?  Since based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#gke_mds) documentation, port 988 is pre defined. Or you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159047/google-kubernetes-engine-networkpolicy-allowing-egress-to-k8s-metadata-proxy) article if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The **noresvport** mount option will tell the client to use a source port above 1024:

```
mount -o noresvport 172.16.1.10:/data /data
```

This of course will work only if the server is not enforcing a privileged port. By a regular NFS servers this is achieved by **insecure** export option:

```
/data *(rw,insecure)
```